# operator=(double) hidden in derived class

Tags: c++

Why does my derived class hide the `operator=(double)` of the base class, while other operators work correctly?

```
struct base
{

double d;

    virtual double operator=(double v)
    {
        return d = v;
    }

    virtual double operator[](int index)
    {
        return d;
    }
};

struct derived : public base
{

};

void main()
{
    derived dv;
    dv = 20.0;  // generates error
    dv[0];      // Works
}
```

Is it possible to expose the `operator=` without redefining it inside derived class?

Comment: You're main must have the return type `int`, not `void`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can expose it like this:

```
struct derived : public base
{
    using base::operator=;
};
```

The call fails because the implicitly generated `operator=(const derived&)` hides the inherited `operator=(double)`.

Answer (score 1):

Operator is still available, but it is hidden. You have to use pointer or a reference to a base class to make virtual call:

```
base *pb = &dv;
pb->operator=( 20.0);
(*pb) = 20.0;
```

Alternatively, to make static call working as well, you can bring base operrator= to scope using `using` declaration:

```
using base::operator=;
```

in class definition.